# Should Dazzle ult his friends or enemies?

Tags: dota-2

Suppose you are playing Dazzle and you sense a team fight is coming.  You are ready to drop your ult, but the way everyone is positioned, you can either drop it on your friends OR your enemies. Which one should you choose and why?

(And, yes, I know it's better if you could do both.  That's not the question here.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are way too many different situations to provide a definite answer.

I can give you a few pointers though:
If your own team lacks a lot of inherent armor (physical damage reduction), and the opponent has a lot of physical damage (often a melee carry or a hard hitting ranged carry) then it might benefit you more throwing the Weave on your own team.

If the roles are reversed, and you can throw Weave on the enemy team and also be certain that your team can chase down the likely to be retreating team. Then that is obviously a great choice.

Similarly if the opposite team mostly dishes out magic damage, then Weave is almost in every situation better applied on the enemies as part of how much more damage your auto-attacks will do (even more so if this takes place early in the game where the armor values are quite low across the board).

I think the question might have to be a bit more specific to be properly answered though.

Comment: +1. Just like to add. When you have great initiation heroes(Tidehunter, Kunkka,Faceless void,Enigma,Puck,Naga siren,Doom etc...), I would definitely throw the weave on the enemy.

Answer (score 1):

Depends heavily on the situation.

primarily, if you have a hero like PA or Sniper who benefit a lot from having targets with much lower armor, while also being less susceptible to focus themselves, use it on the enemy.

if it's an even fight mostly, using it on your own team before the fight allows a longer rampup time for the armor increase, thus meaning there will be a much larger difference than if you use it on the enemy as the fight starts.

a good rule of thumb is, whichever team will take more damage in a fight normally should get the ulti, if the enemy would normally take more damage, amplifying that will allow you to nuke them down faster and lose less health overall, if your team would normally take more damage, the extra armor will give you a big bonus in the fight.

other things to take into account are who has more disables, magic nukes, miss chance skill etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends to be honest, like all the other answers given here.
If you're team is squishy in armour, with heroes like AM, PA or Sniper, then yours of course.
But on the other hand, if your team can dish out a ton of burst damage AOE spells, reducing their armour might help win teamfights.